# Generalized concave property

Tags: functions, inequality, convex-analysis

I know that if $f$ is a concave function, then for $t\in [0,1]$ one has the follow inequality:
$$f(t x+ (1-t)y)\geq t f(x) + (1-t) f(y).$$

But I was wondering if there is a way of generalizing it to finite sums and obtain something like:

$$f\left(\sum_{n=1}^N x_n\right) \geq \dots $$

Comment: The general it's obvious. There is a much more stronger the Popovichui's inequality

Comment: Not really. What you can do is generalise to finite convex combinations:$$f\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \lambda_n x_n\right) \ge \sum_{n=1}^N \lambda_n f(x_n),$$which holds true whenever $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \ge 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N \lambda_n = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

By induction on the number of points, the inequlity generalizes to more than two points and it is called Jensen’s Inequality:

Let $f$ be real concave function, $x_{n} \in \text{dom}(f)$ and positive weights $t_{n}$ for $n = 1, ..., N$, then
$$
f\left(
\frac{\sum t_{n}x_{n}}{\sum t_{n}}
\right) \geq 
\frac{\sum t_{n} f(x_{n})}{\sum t_{n}}
$$

If all the weights $t_{n}$ are equal, it simplifies to
$$
f\left(
\frac{\sum x_{n}}{N}
\right) \geq 
\frac{\sum f(x_{n})}{N}
$$

The inequality also generalizes to infinite sums, integrals, and expected values. For example:

$$
f(\mathbb{E}x) \geq \mathbb{E}f(x)
$$